# MVC .NET, can't find a view

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I'm beginning to learn asp.net and i find a little issue, I create a controller and then the view but for some reason the controller doesn't find the view, i have read so many answer from others questions but i cant resolve it, Here is a screenshoot of my project structure, can someone help me?

[MVC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BWQML.png)

Comment: Are you getting an error message? If not can you put a break point in your controller and step through the code.

Answer (score 1):

Validate the Build Action of your view file. It should be "content"

[image]

Comment: its actually in "content". and still the problem.

Comment: Can you show the response or the exception stack trace?

Comment: i fix it, if you can see in my screenshoot, my actionResult is call "Index", i just change it to 'DisplayCustomer' and its fixed

Comment: Right but you put the viewName